# Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists

Tags: c#, recursion

> `Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists`

I'm using recursion to add up the sum of a list to 1 decimal place but I cannot find the error.

```
double[] arr = { -1.103f, 2.2f, 3.1f, 10.0f, 15.0f, 23.1f, 22, 12f };

List<double> values = new List<double>(arr.Length);

foreach (double i in arr)
{
    values.Add(i);
}

static double sum(List<double> values, int position = 0)
{
    if (values[position] == values[values.Count - 1])
    {
        return values[values.Count - 1];
    }
    return Math.Round(values[position], 2) + sum(values, position + 1);
}

return sum(values);
```

The last return value causes the error message.

Why does it work with `console.WriteLine` but not `return`?

How do I fix it so it works with `return`?

Comment: we need the method where this line: `return sum(values); //this is the return value that causes the error` is situated

Comment: *Use the debugger* and see what `values` is when you get to that line.

Comment: Unrelated, but also: If you have discrete values, you can populate the List directly. You don't need to take a detour via an array. => See second snippet in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/collections#using-a-simple-collection

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this:

```
return sum(values);
```

Your code isn't *in a method*, it's a relatively new C# feature called [Top-level Statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements).  When you *return* from top-level statements, you're producing an "exit code" for the application.  And...

1. Exit codes are *integers* (hence the error, you're returning a `double`)
2. Exit codes *have a meaning* (you don't want to return just any random value)

If you want to *output* the value, then output it instead of returning it from the application:

```
Console.WriteLine(values);
```

> why it works with console.WriteLine but not return

Because `Console.WriteLine` is a method which accepts [a variety of types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline).  `return` is a statement which returns a value from a method.

In this case that "method" is *effectively* an implicit `Main()` method for the application, which has a return type of `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly your mistake is in the way you do your sum.

Start your arrangement directly as a list and convert your list into statics because your method is static:

```
static List<double*> Numbers = new List<double>{ -1.103f, 2.2f, 3.1f, 10.0f, 15.0f, 23.1f, 22, 12f };
```

That avoids the unnecessary creation of the array. If it is necessary to start the object in an array and you need to make validations before adding them to the list, your process is good.

Then use LINQ expressions(`using System.Linq;`) for your sum:

```
static void SumList() => Console.WriteLine(Numbers.Sum().ToString("N0"));
```

That generates a method called SumList that will return the sum of the list since in your code you use a static method places it like this.